# How to set selected area in ChromiumWebBrowser using WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, cefsharp

I have a working WPF application with ChromiumWebBrowser.
Now i need to implement a new task to my project

I guess, there would be a drag-able rectangle on browser to select a area after clicking the apply button that selected area would be only shown in browser.
And the browser size will copy the rectangle size.

I want to achieve something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOLqA1gcCLs

Comment: `CefSharp` renders each frame as an image, it's a native `WPF` control, so you can perform transforms on it like you would any other. Something like stackoverflow.com/a/6817704/4583726 may work, or there are bound to be other examples on how to crop an image. The test will be to see how the rendering performs

Comment: Thanks, I think this may help me. How can i draw a re sizable and drag-able rectangle on cefsharp browser to select an area on browser?

Comment: Any technique that works in `WPF` should work, so maybe search in the context of image cropping.

Comment: I am almost done. Final thing is left that.. I want set the cropped browser to 0,0 position with top bar, rest should be hidden..